# Задача на изолированность единицы в матрице

Tags: python, функции, матрицы

Решаю задачу на Stepik, не проходит по одному из тестов. У себя проверяю в итоге всегда выдаёт True если нет единиц подряд (например [0,0][0,1]) и False (например [0,0][1,1]). Скорее всего не так понял условие задачи, но уже жалко свои труды, хочется конкретно свой код доработать.
**Вот условие задачи:**
*Вводится таблица целых чисел (см. пример ниже) размером N x N элементов (N определяется по входным данным). Эта таблица содержит нули, но кое-где - единицы. С помощью функции с именем verify, на вход которой передается двумерный список чисел, необходимо проверить, являются ли единицы изолированными друг от друга......То есть, функция is_isolate должна возвращать True, если единица изолирована и False - в противном случае.
Как только встречается не изолированная единица, функция verify должна возвращать False. Если успешно доходим (по элементам списка) до конца, то возвращается значение True...*
**Мой код (понимаю , что громоздкий но всё же):**

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = [a]
while len(b) < len(a):
    b.append(list(map(int, input().split()))[:len(a)])


def is_isolate(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        x = lst[i]
        y = lst[i + 1]
        if (x + y) > 1:
            return False
    return True


def verify(lst_array):
    for lst in lst_array:
        if 1 in lst:
            return is_isolate(lst)
    return True


print(verify(b))
```

Comment: Проверьте тест `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]`

Comment: На `[[1, 0], [1, 0]]` тоже не будет работать. Или еще `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]`. Т.е. 1. нужно проверять не только в одной строке, но и по вертикали между строками 2. нужно продолжать проверять, даже если в данной строке все ок

Comment: [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]] - у меня выдает ответ с True

Comment: В условии задачи не сказано что единицы должны быть изолированы и по отношению к соседним спискам ...1], [1... , на это я не проверял

Comment: получается 1ца должна быть окружена нулями в матрице слева, справа, сверху, снизу ? Тогда да, нужно доработать, подскажите хоть немного , а то реально обидно. И вообще задачи для новичков нужно доводить более чётко